# Don't count visits by poster as a view

Tags: feature-request

I apparently ask totally uninteresting questions. When I visit my questions I frequently see the view count go up by one...I.e. I look in on the question and it goes from 4 views to 5.  I don't know if this is caused by my using a different device or the time, but given that I'm logged in, it should be possible to exclude my views from the count.

This may not bother a lot of people, but it sure bothers me.  Can it be fixed?

Update a couple of years later: I still ask uninteresting questions, and my view count still goes up when I visit them.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/do-not-count-views-of-the-asker

Comment: I totally agree with you. This issue shall be fixed. It makes no sense to count OP visits.

Comment: I hope this is fixed too, came here to post the same [meta-tag:feature-request] to find it had already been posted. A shame it hasn't had much traffic/support